# Interfacing a melody generator IC that drives speaker directly to an amplifier

Tags: audio, pwm, dac

**[EDIT]**

I have figured out the solution before, but forgot to update here. Actually you can just connect the two polarity of the amplifier directly to the two speaker out wires, which leads to a completely normal and clear audio quality. But if doing so, the signal may be too high for the amp, connecting an resisitor divider can solve this. Or even better, like one of the answer suggested, use an isolation transformer after the divider, which will isolate the output of melody generator from the amplifier. And actually this is how the product "Car Audio High to Low Level Converter", that you use to interface car audio that only comes with amplified speaker output to another amplifier, works.

However I still don't understand why connecting only one PWM output, along with ground, will bring in the noise. My assumption is that the two PWM output each carry a part of the audio signal, and if you only take one half it won't sound right.

[image: Direct connection]
[image: Use resistor divider]
[image: Use resistor divider along with isolation transformer]

**[Original Question]**

I have a msuic chip and it has a PWM output that drives a speaker directly. Used logic analyzer to check the output frequency which is about 60kHz.
Now I need to connect it to an amplifier. I have tried RC filter but there was a strange noise.
I calculated and adjusted R and C value but this didn't help.
What should I do now?

[image: Circuit from manufacturer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably common mode noise.  Since the chip is driving both ends of the speaker, it is free to add arbitrary common mode signal on top of the differential audio signal.  That common mode signal would mess up attempts to filter and use either of the outputs individually.

Given what the chip does and how it works, the best bet would be to let it drive a audio transformer.  That way the chip can still add whatever common mode signal it wants to.  You can ground one end of the secondary and use the other end as a single-ended audio signal you can feed directly into a power amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely one of those inductorless complimentary class d amps. You can either get an lc filter on one of the outputs to get a se signal or two such filters for a differential signal.